# Android app using LipeRMI is connecting to server but not calling the method

Tags: java, android, rmi

I have an android app and a server, both using [lipeRMI](http://lipermi.sourceforge.net/index.php).
My android app successfully connects to the server. But the method it's supposed to call, is not being called.

Server Code:

```
public interface TestService {

public String getResponse(String data);
}

public class TestServer implements TestService {
public TestServer() {
    try {
        CallHandler callHandler = new CallHandler();
        callHandler.registerGlobal(TestService.class, this);
        Server server = new Server();
        server.bind(7777, callHandler);
        server.addServerListener(new IServerListener() {

            @Override
            public void clientDisconnected(Socket socket) {
                System.out.println("Client Disconnected: " + socket.getInetAddress());
            }

            @Override
            public void clientConnected(Socket socket) {
                System.out.println("Client Connected: " + socket.getInetAddress());
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Server Listening");
    } catch (LipeRMIException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public String getResponse(String data) {
    System.out.println("getResponse called");
    return "Your data: " + data;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestServer testServer = new TestServer();
}

}
```

The android code:

```
interface TestService {

public String getResponse(String data);
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private String serverIP = "192.168.1.7";
EditText et= null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btnGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    et= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    btnGet.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            new Conn().execute();
        }
    });

}
class Conn extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, MainActivity> {

    @Override
    protected MainActivity doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Looper.prepare();

        try {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Inside conn my nigga", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            CallHandler callHandler = new CallHandler();
            Client client = new Client(serverIP, 7777, callHandler);
            TestService testService = (TestService) client.getGlobal(TestService.class);
            String msg = testService.getResponse("qwe");
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, testService.getResponse("abc"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Looper.loop();
        return null;
    }

}
}
```

I tried using the above code also using a simple Runnable thread instead of AsyncTask(I was paranoid AsyncTask'd be causing the problem) but it went in vain.

The server gives this output:

```
Server Listening
Client Connected: /192.168.1.5
Client Disconnected: /192.168.1.5
```

No matter how many times I click the Button1 of my android app.
Any help will be really appreciated. :)
Thank you for your time!

Comment: What exception is thrown?

Comment: No exception at all @EJP. It's like the function never gets called.

Answer (score 1):

I had this situation when packages were different. You should make sure that `TestService` packages are same at Android application and server. 
If you use your own class in `TestService` interface, it should have same packages too and should implement `Serializable`.